# QGIS Trouble with raster layer

Tags: qgis, raster

I am having trouble with this raster layer that I downloaded from PASDA website - "Birds Habitat 2006 - Natural Lands Trust"

The attributes values habitat quality ranked 1-10. It looks like the 
background of this raster image (solid brown) have been assigned one of the values. I tried making the background value transparent - but I lose some of the 
actual data on the raster image that that value represents.

[image]

But if I zoom in close enough to the image the background disappears and the layer appears correctly. [image]

How to get this this layer to appear correctly?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the values of the background pixels?

If you have valid values between 1 and 10, and that background is different, you can tell QGIS to use the value of the background.

Also, I note that the rivers look the same colour, so maybe it's value refers to 'other'. You could look into the metadata for the layer to find out.

But, really, I think you want to set the number that is used as the dark brown to be NODATA in QGIS, which will make it transparent.

Comment: Looking at the data, the surrounding areaa seem to have a value of 128. So set that as an additional transparent value under Properties, Transparency tab.

Comment: Good to know, @AndreJ, mark this answer as the solution if it worked, please. =)

Comment: Thank you both for the responses!  AndreJ -My No Data value was set to 255 - I added 128 and that fixed it. But where/how did you find/determine the value of 128 was needed? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @joed you can interrogate the raster in QGIS (use "i" info tool) and find out.